# tool to send data to tcp port

Tags: c#, .net, windows, sockets

i am building  a simple tcp server in c#, now i wanna test the performance of my app, the quesion is, exist any tool o command to send raw data to an tcp port ?

Comment: what sort of tool? something to just connect and test manually? telnet for windows will do this. something to send specific data? you'll save yourself alot of trouble if you build a simple client too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually just use telnet for that.  It just send raw data and shows raw data -- usually it's meant to be a terminal, but if it's ASCII, you can type and see it.

Answer (score 3):

[netcat](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Netcat)

Answer (score 0):

if you are on vista or the user has WePOS or a similar variant telnet might not be installed, so grab yourself a copy of Putty, it can do Raw stuff, and it can also do Telnet and a number of other nice little tricks